# как в функцию передать структуру

Tags: golang

Мне необходимо передать структуру в функцию, и это должна быть не какая то определенная, а та которая будет необходима в той или иной задачи. Каким образом это можно осуществить или вообще это возможно ли  это?

```
type Robot struct {
        Type    string 
        Model string
    }
type Human struct {
            Live    string 
            Name string 
        }
 func Tasks() ([]*New, error) {
        //тело функции
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать интерфейс, который описывает нужные вам функции. и каждая структура имплементирует этот интерфейс.

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type worker interface {
    DoWork() error
}

type Robot struct {
    Type  string
    Model string
}

func (r *Robot) DoWork() error {
    fmt.Printf("Robot %s %s is doing work\n", r.Type, r.Model)
    return nil
}

type Human struct {
    Live string
    Name string
}

func (h *Human) DoWork() error {
    fmt.Printf("Human %s %s is doing work\n", h.Live, h.Name)
    return nil
}

func Tasks(w worker) error {
    return w.DoWork()
}

func main() {
    r := Robot{
        Type:  "robot",
        Model: "vehicle",
    }

    h := Human{
        Live: "100",
        Name: "Obama",
    }

    err := Tasks(&r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = Tasks(&h)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/KzEZ5_WMBmL

```
Robot robot vehicle is doing work
Human 100 Obama is doing work
```

Comment: Спасибо. ваш ответ указал в каком направлении двигаться